# Please help clarify my regex pattern

Tags: regex

I have the following string:

`<script>m('02:29:1467301/>Sender1*>some text message?<<02:29:13625N1/>Sender2*>Recipient2: another message??<>A<<02:29:1393100=>User1*|0User2*|%></B><<','');</script>`

N.B. messages are separated by <<

I need extract from message the following parts:
1. Time
2. Sender
3. Recipient
4. Text

Recipient may being defined or not, this field is optional.

I do this by the following pattern:
`(?<message>(?<time>\d{1,2}:\d{1,2}:[0-9a-z]+)/>(?<messageData>(?<sender>.+?)\*>(.+?)))<<`

But, I cannot extract recipient separately from the message text.
`(?<message>(?<time>\d{1,2}:\d{1,2}:[0-9a-z]+)/>(?<messageData>(?<sender>.+?)\*>(((?<recipient>.+?):){0,1}(?<messageText>.+?))))<<`

N.B. In the first message no recipient

Please help correct my pattern.

Comment: Who is the recipient of the first message?  The sender is `sender1`, but the recipient appears to be missing.

Comment: In the first message no recipient

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `<recipient>` group pattern needs to exclude `<` and `:` or else it will match the text between `*>` and the timestamp's first colon when the recipient is omitted (as in the first message of your example).

A simple tweak to that group pattern should fix it:

```
(?<message>(?<time>\d{1,2}:\d{1,2}:[0-9a-z]+)/>(?<messageData>(?<sender>.+?)\*>(((?<recipient>[^<:]+):)?(?<messageText>.+?))))<<
```

Note I replaced `{0,1}` with the optional quantifier (`?`). It's just shorthand to improve readability (a little goes a long way). :-)

Speaking of readability, here it is in multi-line form:

```
(?<message>
    (?<time>\d{1,2}:\d{1,2}:[0-9a-z]+)/>
    (?<messageData>
        (?<sender>.+?)\*>
        (
          ((?<recipient>[^<:]+):)?
          (?<messageText>.+?)
        )
    )
)<<
```

I don't know if the unnamed group containing `<recipient>` and `<messageText>` was intentional, but it's unnecessary. You can break it down to this:

```
(?<message>
    (?<time>\d{1,2}:\d{1,2}:[0-9a-z]+)/>
    (?<messageData>
        (?<sender>.+?)\*>
        ((?<recipient>[^<:]+):)?
        (?<messageText>.+?)
    )
)<<
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this out, may fit little better:

```
(?<message>(?<time>\d{1,2}:\d{1,2}:[0-9a-z]*).+?>(?<messageData>(?<sender>.*?)>(((?<recipient>[^<:]+):)?(?<messageText>.*?))))<<
```

P.S. Hi there ;)